# how to create pagination in php with random records but with maintaing previous state

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have create a pagination in php and MySQL which works fine but shows same records every time I refresh the page.

the problem I am facing is how to show new records every time I refresh the page and even maintain the flow.for example if I am on first page its show random records every time.. and when I click in second page and come back to first page..it shows totally different records.
How to solve this.

```
 $selectQ = "select * from primaryinfo order by rand(3)";
$result = mysql_query($selectQ);
$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);
$start;
$end;
if (isset($_POST['pagecc']))
{
$show_page = $_POST['pagecc'];  
if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
{
    $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
    $end = $start + $per_page;
} else
{ 
    $start = 0;              
    $end = $per_page;
}
}
 else
{ 
$start = 0;
$end = $per_page;
} 
if($end > $total_results)
    $end = $total_results; 

 ///$totlaRecords = mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error());
 for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++){
 //displaying here...
 }
```

this is how I did pagination...hope this could help..

thank in advance.

Comment: Pagination on a result set that is sorted randomly is strange to begin with. Can you explain why you made it this way?

Comment: Or pagination on a rapidly changing data set?

Comment: not stored randomly nor i want changing data set.. I need to have a pagination which shows new records on every refresh but when i shift to next page and come back  to previous page it should show the same result

Comment: Store your random order in an array or in the session, then bounce over that by the number page you're on so: 4 records per page, if you are on page 2, it will pull from the array keys 4->7, page 3 = 8->11 and so on

Comment: Daniel, ya that would work but if on page 1 I dont know what rand() query is going to return, how could i store them in array..correct me if m wrong..

Comment: You set the array before you run the script for your list. You use each page as displaying key n - n+4 or whatever the number of results per page, using the array key values as the id of the result in your database.

Comment: @Daniel: That's basically the effect of using `RAND(N)`, except you would only need to keep the seed value.

Comment: @Alix - Yes, right, I've found dealing direct with MySQL a bit hit and miss with rand.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't follow. `RAND(N)` is not the most efficient thing ever, but it's reliable to the OP purposes.

Comment: I agree, RAND(N) is probably good enough too but we have both come up with viable options for him to use.

Answer (score 4):

Seed [`RAND(N)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> If a constant integer argument N is specified, it is used as the seed value, which produces a repeatable sequence of column values. In the following example, note that the sequences of values produced by RAND(3) is the same both places where it occurs.

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND(CONSTANT_INT_VALUE);
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de022/7)

`CONSTANT_INT_VALUE` should be a constant integer value maintened across requests.

Of the top of my head, you could use the decimal representation of the client IP address for instance.

Comment: it would be generating random on every page..even if you come back to previous page...

Comment: @user1940803: No, it wouldn't. The results would be ordered randomly, but with a consistent random order (even across page requests, as long as you use the same seed).

Comment: @user1940803: As for the seed, you could use the IP base 10 representation, or just store the return value of `mt_rand()` in session / APC / memcache and use that.

Comment: its the same...its showing random on first page..even maintaining the state but...its same for every refresh..can we start randomly from a record and proceed with it to and fro.

Comment: select * from primaryinfo order by rand(3)... this is the query and above the pagination code

Comment: @user1940803: Where are the pagination clauses (`LIMIT` / `OFFSET`) in there?! See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de022/7 for a working example.

Comment: m not using any of them..that will be handled by the php code

Comment: @user1940803: Then no wonder you're seeing the same randomized results on all pages.

Comment: @user1940803: Show some code and actual / expected output if you need further help.

Comment: @user1940803: You should paginate your results directly in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.. Form what i understand.
consider no of records on a single page must be 'x'. So,
`mysql_query("select * from primaryinfo LIMIT 0,x");`

For second page
`mysql_query("select * from primaryinfo LIMIT x,2x");`
So this would show the next records and when you return to first page they would not repeat.

Answer (score -2):

Try in your sql add `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: The question says, '...but with maintaing previous state'